# Storing Map using SpringData

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data

I'm getting following JSON from REST Service (170~ rates)

```
{
  "success":true,
  "timestamp":1527944949,
  "base":"EUR",
  "date":"2018-06-02",
  "rates":{
    "AED":4.284515,
    "AFN":83.084064,
    "ALL":124.882747,
    ....
  }
}
```

And I'd like to persist it on my DB with following class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "exchange_rate")
public class ExchangeRateEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(unique = true)
    private Date date;

    @ElementCollection
    @MapKeyColumn(name="name")
    @Column(name="value")
    @CollectionTable(name="rates", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="date"))
    private Map<String, Double> rates;

    //getters and setters
}
```

If I understand correctly, it should make new table "rates" with data I want? But it ends up with

> MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'currency_rate.rates' doesn't exist

where currency_rate is my db name

I'v tried to change to

```
@CollectionTable(name="exchange_rate", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="date"))
```

but it gives me

> MappingException: Foreign key
>   (FK9s46rfp5jp46vm7ep4cbc020x:exchange_rate [date])) must have same
>   number of columns as the referenced primary key (exchange_rate
>   [date,name])

And I'm totaly confused, how to store Map in DB?

Comment: Well, the error is quite clear: you just didn't create the database table (rates) that is needed to store the rates. Just do it.

Comment: You can serialize it to json.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try convert Json data to POJO using Jackson framework.

Example:

```
String json = "{ \"color\" : \"Black\", \"type\" : \"BMW\" }";
Car car = objectMapper.readValue(json, Car.class);
```

2. Record in the Database will create only thwn when table 'currency rate' real exist.
   You may write `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false` in application config file then table will create automatically.
3. Error `MappingException: Foreign key (FK9s4...` it due to not correct entity relations. But you wrote only one entity.